# Issue with starting datanode in single node cluster

Tags: hadoop

Hi I am setting a single node cluster. When I try to execute `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`, all nodes except datanode start. When I start data node forcefully, it starts for a while but stops after say 1-2 minutes. How do I overcome this?

Comment: Post your `datanode` logs.

Comment: clear the datanode directory and start it again. Check the directory permissions of datanode